# ¿Cómo evitar que con removeClass() se remueven las clases anteriores?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy usando `removeClass()` para remover una clase que lo que hace es que me convierte el text en discos/asteriscos (*****), como un password. El problema es que cuando lo utilizo me remueve los discos de la fila anterior.

Este es el código:

```js
$(".add-row").click(function() {
  var param = $("#param").val();
  var valor = $("#valor").val();
  var markup = "<tr><td><input type='button' class='delete-row button green' value='Eliminar' name='record'></td><td><input type='button' class='delete-row button blue' value='Editar' name='record'></td><td>" + param + "</td><td class='hidetext'>" + valor + "</td></tr>";

  $("table tbody").append(markup);

  if (!document.getElementById("myCheck").checked) {
    $('.hidetext').removeClass('hidetext');
  }

  $('input[type="text"]').val('');
  $('input[type="password"]').val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="span-23 margin_bot margin_top_b text_form_fieldname">
  <form>
    <input class="input_text input_size text_input span-6" type="text" id="param" placeholder="Parametro">
    <input class="input_text input_size text_input span-6" type="text" id="valor" placeholder="Valor">
    <input class="myCheck" type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="showPassword()">Ocultar
    <input type="button" class="add-row button blue" value="Agregar">
  </form>
  <br>
  <table style="width: 50%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Parametro</th>
        <th>Valor
          <th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Tengo una idea de que es porque lo que debería hacer es crea el string con o sin la clases antes de hacer el append pero no estoy seguro como hacerlo.

Comment: Deberias de incluir todo el HTML, incluyendo el checkbox `myCheck`

Comment: No lo agregues en un comentario, edita tu pregunta para ver que relacion tiene con la tabla que pusiste.

Comment: Lo que quieres es que puedas mostrar el password de una fila nada mas?

Comment: No veo en que parte de tu código pasan las cosas que pones en la pregunta. Deberías tratar de explicar mejor lo que pasa y lo que quieres lograr.

Comment: `$('.hidetext').removeClass('hidetext');` remueve todos los `hidetext`

Comment: ¿puedes redactar un poco mejor tu pregunta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias evaluar tu condición antes de hacer el append de esta manera

```
$(".add-row").click(function() {
    var param = $("#param").val();
    var valor = $("#valor").val();
    var hideClass = document.getElementById("myCheck").checked ? "hidetext" : ""
    var markup = "<tr><td><input type='button' class='delete-row button green' value='Eliminar' name='record'></td><td><input type='button' class='delete-row button blue' value='Editar' name='record'></td><td>" + param + "</td><td class='" + hideClass + "'>" + valor + "</td></tr>";

    $("table tbody").append(markup);

    $('input[type="text"]').val('');
    $('input[type="password"]').val('');
  });
```

Comment: Esto me funcionó perfecto gracias!